# How set ngModel for span Angular 6?

Tags: angular, html, typescript, angular6

**HTML5**

```
<div class="row rating" style="float:right;">
     <span class="fa fa-star"  name="val1" [(ngModel)]="data.val1"></span>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
data = {
 val1 = ''
}
```

**Note:** I need a unique name. I want to use the star rate system. I want to get name **ONLY**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Approaches

**Interpolation**

```
<div class="row rating" style="float:right;">
     <span class="fa fa-star"  name="val1">{{data.val1}}</span>
</div>
```

**Property binding**

```
<div class="row rating" style="float:right;">
     <span class="fa fa-star"  name="val1" [innerHTML]="data.val1"></span>
</div>
```

> When rendering data values as strings, there is no technical reason to
>   prefer one form to the other. You lean toward readability, which tends
>   to favor interpolation. You suggest establishing coding style rules
>   and choosing the form that both conforms to the rules and feels most
>   natural for the task at hand.

**Note:**

> the Angular NgModel directive is a bridge that enables two-way binding
>   to form elements.

[Template syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#html-in-templates)

Comment: after adding val1 = '1' was change shape from star to 1

Comment: I want only name

Comment: Could you leave an example of how that would be in plain HTML?

Answer (score 1):

ngModel can only be used for inputs (it needs to be some form elements). I think what you are looking for is angular interpolation through which you can display data from component model

```
<div class="row rating" style="float:right;">
     <span class="fa fa-star"  name="val1">{{data.val1}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: How to get name to TS

Comment: this is my a qeustion